# POCO C++ - NET SSL - how to POST HTTPS request

Tags: c++, http, post, https, poco-libraries

How to correctly do a POST to HTTPS server and embed the login data correctly. Below code does not return any cookies (in Wininet it does). I wonder how POCO HTTP library handles HTTP redirections?

```
MyApp()
{
    try
    {
        const Poco::URI uri( "https://localhost.com" );
        const Poco::Net::Context::Ptr context( new Poco::Net::Context( Poco::Net::Context::CLIENT_USE, "", "", "rootcert.pem" ) );
        Poco::Net::HTTPSClientSession session(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort(), context );
        Poco::Net::HTTPRequest req(Poco::Net::HTTPRequest::HTTP_POST, "/login.php" );
        req.setContentType("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
        req.setKeepAlive(true);

        std::string reqBody("username=???&password=???&action_login=Log+In\r\n\r\n");
        req.setContentLength( reqBody.length() );

        //Poco::Net::HTTPBasicCredentials cred("???", "???");
        //cred.authenticate(req);
        session.sendRequest(req) << reqBody;
        Poco::Net::HTTPResponse res;
        std::istream& rs = session.receiveResponse(res);
        std::string resp;

        std::vector<Poco::Net::HTTPCookie> cookies;
        res.getCookies( cookies );
    }
    catch( const Poco::Net::SSLException& e )
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << ": " << e.message() << std::endl;
    }
    catch( const std::exception& e )
    {
        std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;;
    }

};
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are setting content type like this:

```
req.setContentType("Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
```

which should be:

```
req.setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n");
```