# How do I make an HTTP Post with HTTP Basic Authentication, using POCO?

Tags: c++, http, post, basic-authentication, poco-libraries

I'm trying to make an HTTP Post with HTTP Basic Authentication (cleartext username and password), using POCO.  I found an example of a Get and have tried to modify it, but being a rookie I think I've mangled it beyond usefulness.  Anyone know how to do this?

Yes, I've already seen the other SO question on this: [POCO C++ - NET SSL - how to POST HTTPS request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1499086/poco-c-net-ssl-how-to-post-https-request), but I can't make sense of how it is trying to implement the username and password part.  I also don't understand the use of "x-www-form-urlencoded". Is this required for a Post? I don't have a form.  Just want to POST to the server with username and password parameters.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Finally. Here's how you do it:

```
HTTPClientSession session("yourdomain.com");
session.setKeepAlive(true);

Poco::Net::HTTPRequest req(Poco::Net::HTTPRequest::HTTP_POST, "/myapi.php/api/validate", HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);
req.setContentType("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
req.setKeepAlive(true); // notice setKeepAlive is also called on session (above)

std::string reqBody("username=user1@yourdomain.com&password=mypword");
req.setContentLength( reqBody.length() );

std::ostream& myOStream = session.sendRequest(req); // sends request, returns open stream
myOStream << reqBody;  // sends the body

req.write(std::cout);

Poco::Net::HTTPResponse res;
std::istream& iStr = session.receiveResponse(res);  // get the response from server
std::cerr << iStr.rdbuf();  // dump server response so you can view it
```

Comment: In the code, you have an explicit comment on using `setKeepAlive()` on both the session and the request. Could you possibly edit your answer to explain the purpose of both, and what the effect of leaving one or either out is?

Comment: And is there any reason you do not use `HTTPBasicCredentials`?

Comment: No, no deliberate reason I didn't use HTTPBasicCredentials.  I wasn't aware of a lot of things back then.  Was kind of thrown into iOS and had other projects going to.  Will have to answer your 1st questions later.

Comment: +1 as you helped me answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44333630/how-to-exchange-code-for-token-in-spotify/44354280#44354280

If you are still around maybe you can help me get the authorization code using Poco Net.

Comment: I see you ended up answering your own question too :)

Comment: @CashCow -- Yes. I've done this more than once in fact.  You seriously need a solution and then when you find it you feel obligated to share and not just go on your way.  As you can see this answer has helped a few people.

Answer (score 3):

When you do an HTTP POST, typically the data that is being sent to the server is sent in one of two forms:

- Name,Value pairs where the name and value are separated by "=", and distinct pairs are separated by "&". For example: `var1=value1&var2=value2`. Also, these name value pairs are sent so that certain special characters and non-alphanumeric characters are replaced by `%HH`, a percent sign and two hexadecimal digits representing the ASCII code of the character. For example, if value for the first parameter included an "#", it would be sent as `var1=value1%23&var2=value2`. When sending data in this format, the client is required to insert a Content-Type header with the value `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` so that the server may be able to decode the data correctly.
- As a multipart MIME body where each part can be large in size as well as include "non-escaped" data (including binary data). Different MIME parts are separated by a string delimiter (boundary) that does not appear within any of the MIME "payloads". When sending data in this format, the client is required to insert a Content-Type header with the value `multipart/form-data`.

In the case of the previous StackOverflow question you referenced, the request body is being sent in the first manner as shown above. Hope that clarifies.

Regards,
Siddharth

Comment: Siddhart, that does clarify a bit.  Thanks.  Have you used POCO? If you can offer code that will successfully Post with uname and pword using the POCO library I'll mark your answer as correct.

Answer (score 2):

From the POCO library credential test, here is the code:

```
HTTPRequest request;
assert (!request.hasCredentials());

HTTPBasicCredentials cred("user", "secret");
cred.authenticate(request);
assert (request.hasCredentials());
std::string scheme;
std::string info;
request.getCredentials(scheme, info);
assert (scheme == "Basic");
assert (info == "dXNlcjpzZWNyZXQ=");

HTTPBasicCredentials cred2(request);
assert (cred2.getUsername() == "user");
assert (cred2.getPassword() == "secret");
```

When sending the request, you would only use the first part of this code (stopping at `cred.authenticate(request)`).